# WPF Combobox ItemSource not updating after delete

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a problem updating my Combobox. I've implemented INotifyPropertyChanged. Everything is working great, it's binded. So this is my Combobox:

```
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Documents, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,Mode=TwoWay}"
              DisplayMemberPath="BrDokumentaDatum"
              SelectedValuePath="IdDokumenta"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentDocument, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              SelectedIndex="0">
        </ComboBox>
```

This is my ViewModel:

```
        private ObservableCollection<Dokument> documents;
        public ObservableCollection<Dokument> Documents 
    {
        get
        {
            return this.documents;
        }
        set
        {
            this.documents = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Documents");
        }
    }
```

I have a Command which is binded to my button

```
        public ICommand DeleteDocumentCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.deleteDocumentCommand == null)
            {
                this.deleteDocumentCommand = new CommandBase(i => this.DeleteDocument(), null);
            }

            return this.deleteDocumentCommand;
        }
    }
```

DeleteDocument() calls my service:

```
        private void DeleteDocument()
    {
        if (confirm("Želite li obrisati odabrani dokument", "Obriši dokment"))
        {
            bool deleted = serviceClient.DeleteDocument(this.CurrentDocument.IdDokumenta);
        }
    }
```

My Document is deleted. My combobox does not update with new item source.
What's the problem?

Comment: how does your serviceClient.DeleteDocument method interact with the existing Documents ObservableCollection on your viewmodel? Are you actually removing this document from this collection?

Comment: What are you doing in the serviceClient.DeleteDocument method? - please show the code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not seeing any code there that removes the `Dokument` from the `Documents` ObservableCollection.

You can delete it from the underlying data repository, but the `Documents` property is totally disconnected from that and will still hold a copy of the data entity.